# "Компетенція" і "компетентність": чи є різниця?

Tags: вживання-слів, різниця-між-словами, синоніми, іменники

Неодноразово чула вживання слів "компетенція" та "компетентність" в одному контексті, хотілось би зрозуміти, чи є насправді якась різниця між ними.

В [Академічному словнику української мови](http://sum.in.ua/s/kompetencija) та [тут](http://rozum.org.ua/index.php?a=term&d=18&t=18479) міститься таке тлумачення слова "компетенція":

> **компетенція**; ж.  (лат., від взаємно прагну; відповідаю, підходжу)
>
> 1. Добра обізнаність із чим-небудь.
> 2. Коло повноважень якої-небудь організації, установи або особи; коло питань, в яких дана особа має певні повноваження, знання, досвід і
>    т.ін.

Щодо "[компетентності](http://rozum.org.ua/index.php?a=term&d=18&t=18478)":

> **компетентність**; ж.  поінформованість, обізнаність, авторитетність.

Звертаю увагу, що у тлумаченні обох слів йдеться про обізнаність, тобто, якщо відкинути перше значення слова "компетенція" про коло повноважень, то вони означатиметь те саме: добру обізнаність?

У [Академічному словнику української мови](http://sum.in.ua/s/kompetentnyj) одним з тлумачень поняття "компетентний" є таке:

> 2. Який має певні повноваження; повноправний, повновладний.

Тобто за цим тлумаченням значення слів зводиться до певного кола повноважень, з чого роблю висновок, що слова є синонімами.

*Отже, чи є різниця між словами "компетентність" і "компетенція" і як правильно їх вживати?*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Часто справді ці 2 слова використовують як синонімні і у певних словосполученнях замінюють їх одне одним. Однак між ними є відмінність. Про це йдеться у статті ***Лойко С. В. ["ПОНЯТТЯ «КОМПЕТЕНЦІЯ» ТА
«КОМПЕТЕНТНІСТЬ»: ТЕОРЕТИЧНИЙ АНАЛІЗ"](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0ahUKEwi248KKra3aAhXMkiwKHesICIkQFggnMAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.irbis-nbuv.gov.ua%2Fcgi-bin%2Firbis_nbuv%2Fcgiirbis_64.exe%3FC21COM%3D2%26I21DBN%3DUJRN%26P21DBN%3DUJRN%26IMAGE_FILE_DOWNLOAD%3D1%26Image_file_name%3DPDF%2Fpptp_2013_4_15.pdf&usg=AOvVaw3mg7b4nVNnYal6hYd-ebNy)***:

> У деяких наукових працях, терміни компетенція і компетентність
>   вживаються як *синоніми (Дж. Равен)*, у інших вони *чітко
>   розмежовуються (В.В. Краєвський, А.В. Хуторський)*.

Автор у цій статті аналізує різноманітні праці, зокрема й академічні видання, у яких подано значення лексем "компетенція" і "компетентність". Сюди належить наведений Вами *СУМ, Тлумачний словник англійської мови, 1993; Словник іншомовних слів; Латино-російський словник*. Також наводяться і визначення у розумінні *В.Д. Шадрикова, С.Е. Шишова, Дж. Спектор, Кучай О. В* та ін.

Автор робить висновок, що:

> під **компетенцією** слід розуміти певну *сферу, коло діяльності, наперед
>   визначену систему питань щодо яких особистість повинна бути добре
>   обізнана, тобто володіти певним набором знань, умінь, навичок та
>   власного до них ставлення*.
>
> **Компетентність** – *якість особистості, її
>   певне надбання, що ґрунтується на знаннях, досвіді, моральних
>   засадах і проявляється в критичний момент за рахунок вміння
>   знаходити зв’язок між ситуацією та знаннями, у прийнятті адекватних
>   рішень нагальної проблеми*.

Також ще у статті **Леонтян М. А. ["ПОНЯТТЯ «КОМПЕТЕНЦІЯ» І «КОМПЕТЕНТНІСТЬ» У ТЕОРІЇ ОСВІТИ"](http://pednauki.chdu.edu.ua/article/viewFile/81299/76766)** подана доволі хороша таблиця, яку автор ділить на такі блоки: 1) дослідник, джерело; 2) зміст означення компетенція / компетентність. З-поміж усіх найбільше сподобалось Рубіна Ю. Б.:

> **Компетентність** – сукупність компетенцій;
>
> **Компетенція** - особиста  властивість  спеціаліста  вирішувати  визначений  тип професійних задач.

Проте вже у висновку читаємо:

> Сутність визначення компетенції у тлумаченні різними  дослідниками  розкривається  через  поняття «знання», «уміння», «навички», «отриманий досвід
>   » і  здібності,  які  надбано  і  розвинуто  завдяки навчанню. Також «компетенція» ототожнюється з колом питань, в яких людина добре обізнана.
>
> **Компетентність**, на нашу думку, є ***результатом набуття*** **компетенцій**.
>
> Компетентність має складовий елемент  готовності  до  виконання  поставленої задачі,  а  також  включає  в  своє  поняття  елементи  особистісних характеристик людини (мобільності, ініціативності тощо.)
>
> На  нашу  думку  *слід  розрізняти  поняття «компетенція» і «компетентність»,   оскільки компетентність,  на  відміну  від  компетенції  (що містить в собі ключові поняття "знання", «уміння» та «навички» та ін.), які передбачають дію людини за  стандартною  ситуацією, має  в  собі  елемент 
>   готовності   до   ситуації   через   особистісну характеристику  людини,  через  перехід  від  якості знання  до  якості  діяльності,  яка  може  бути 
>   нестандартною.*  І  тому  за  своєю  суттю  **поняття «компетентність» є  значно  ширшим  від  поняття «компетенція»**.